# Retrieve DNS query information from a Cloudflare zone using GraphQL

Tags: python, graphql, cloudflare

I have the following GraphQL query which returns me the information from Cloudflare's analytics dashboard like cachedBytes, cachedRequests.

```
query {
  viewer {
    zones(filter: {zoneTag: "%s"}) {
      httpRequests1dGroups(orderBy: [date_ASC], limit: 100, filter: {date_geq: "2021-11-24", date_lt: "2021-12-24"}) {
        dimensions {
          date
        }
        sum {
          bytes
          cachedBytes
          cachedRequests
          contentTypeMap {
            bytes
            requests
            edgeResponseContentTypeName
          }
          requests

        }
        uniq {
          uniques
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know how to retrieve DNS query information from a Cloudflare zone?

Answer (score 0):

DNS information is not currently part of the [GraphQL datasets](https://developers.cloudflare.com/analytics/graphql-api/features/data-sets#available-data-sets). But you can use the standard Cloudflare API to retrieve DNS Analytics data: [here is the documentation (DNS Analytics)](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-analytics-properties)